# Using a Delphi native dll in C# (DllImport issue)

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I'm having issues importing a Delphi native dll to .net. 
I'm getting *System.EntryPointNotFoundException*.

**Here's my delphi dll:**

```
procedure ProcedimientoEncriptar(texto,clave,resultado:PChar); export stdcall;
    var ...
    begin
    ....
    ....
    end;

    exports
      ProcedimientoEncriptar ;
```

**And here's my DllImport on .Net (C#) code:**

```
[DllImport("CryptoDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern void ProcedimientoEncriptar([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string texto, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string clave, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder resultado);
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Diego.

Comment: That's not your actual code I think. A Delphi `function` is meant to have a return value. But yours doesn't. And your C# code has `void` return. Is your Delphi code really `function`? Isn't it `procedure`. Your Delphi code in the question doesn't compile. Please use copy/paste when putting code in questions. Don't post fake code.

Comment: You're right, it was `procedure` but i changed it for testing purposes (i tried returning a `PChar`).

Comment: What Delphi version? Is `PChar` Unicode or not?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm pretty new to Delphi but I'm using Embarcadero's Solution (Borland Developer Studio 2006)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only explanation for `System.EntryPointNotFoundException` is that the DLL that the C# code is finding is not the DLL produced from the Delphi code that you show. So, perhaps the C# code is picking up an out of date version of the DLL. Or perhaps it's picking up a completely different DLL.

For example, my system has a DLL named `cryptdll.dll` in the system32 directory. Most likely that's the DLL that your C# code is finding.

In order to make sure that the right DLL is found, you need to place a copy of the Delphi DLL in the same directory as the C# executable file.

Comment: Thanks, David, that was the issue. I didn't know that a 'cryptdll.dll' existed on the system.

I renamed and copied the dll to the /bin/ directory and it worked (it's an ASP .Net application).

Cheers, Diego.

Comment: @Diego Iturriaga: David is right. In windows, the location of a D.L.L. can be a problem, and is not related to been Delphi generated, in this case, the same error can happen to a D.L.L. compiled in other language, and wrong filesystem location.